# Can a stage get triggered independently?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

For an application, we are thinking of a single Jenkins pipeline with 3 stages. It is a scripted pipeline.

---

**Dev** stage supposed to  get triggered on every latest commit of `develop` branch

**QA** stage suppose to get triggered on specific commit(go ready) on `develop` branch, before a `release` branch gets forked from `develop` branch.

**Prod** stage supposed to get triggered on merge commit on `master` branch from `release` branch.

---

Something like this:

```
node('worker_node'){
   stage('Dev-stage'){}
   stage('QA-stage'){}
   stage('Prod-stage'){} 
}
```

---

Can `stage(){}`  get triggered independently?

or

Is `stage('QA-stage'){}` supposed to get immediately triggered after `stage('Dev-stage'){}`?

Comment: AFAIK the stages will all happen sequentially. To filter to just a branch if use an if block `if (env.BRANCH_NAME = 'develop') { ...`

Comment: @evolutionxbox you should put this as an answer

Comment: Maybe. I’m pretty sure I learnt this from another stackoverflow question. Just looking for it now.

Answer (score 1):

As @evolutionxbox mentioned in the comment, the stages will always run sequentially. Ideally, you should have different jobs for different steps, because if you are never going to use all the stages in one job then it beats the whole purpose of stages. You can have them in a common jenkinsfile if you want and have if block over stages like:

```
if(env.PARAM=="Value"){
    stage('required stage'){
        //code
    }
}
```

Or you can call different functions based on your condition in the same file:

```
stage('common'){
    if(env.PARAM=="Value"){
        commons.funct1()
    }
}
```

here commons variable loads another file (`def commons=load('somefile.groovy')`).